# Spring Boot not running schema.sql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am having an issue running the schema.sql upon running the program.

In my pom.xml, I already have the mysql config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

I only have one class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {...}
```

Under src/resources, I have schema.sql containing:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;

CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);
```

Under src/resources, I have application.yml containing:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
spring.datasource.url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample?useSSL=false"
spring.datasource.username: "****"
spring.datasource.password: "****"
```

I have confirmed that I am able to connect to the database "sample" upon starting the application, however, it's not creating the table.  Please advise.

Comment: application.yml or application.properties?

Comment: application.yml

Comment: but format you put above is of properties file. not yml file

Comment: yml can also have this format, not just the indented one

Answer (score 10):

That's because Spring Boot has check in `DataSourceInitializer's initSchema()` method.

[image]

It will execute scripts only if your database is of type `H2,DERBY,HSQL`

However, you can override this behaviour by using following setting in application.properties

```
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

[DataSourceInitializer.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceInitializer.java)
[EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/306c79f0de3166288a9bdc570776b7743b58b5c7/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/jdbc/EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java)

Comment: Thanks. This only works for Embedded DB's and not for the actual DB.

Comment: I'm using H2 db but even with these application.property settings, it's still not working

Comment: `spring.datasource.initialization-mode` is deprecated in favor of `spring.sql.init.mode` in latest versions of spring.

Answer (score 6):

In my case (Spring Boot 2.0.0+) it worked as expected only when property setting  `spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always` was combined with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`.

Answer (score 1):

From spring boot version 2.7 onward, this will work:

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```